# discord.js channelCreate() event is triggered when joining a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, discord.js

When a bot joins a server, it is triggering 2 events. 1st is the guildCreate event, and the second is the channelCreate event.
Here is my events loader:

```
const ascii = require("ascii-table");
let table = new ascii("Events");
table.setHeading("Event", "Load status");
const load = async () => {
    const evtFiles = await readdir("./events");
    var total = 0;

    evtFiles.forEach(file => {
        if (file.split(".").slice(-1)[0] !== "js") return;
        const evtName = file.split(".")[0];
        const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
        table.addRow(file, '✅');
        client.on(evtName, event.bind(null, client));
        delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./events/${file}`)];
        total = total +1;

    })
    console.log(table.toString());
    console.log(`Total no of events ${total} loaded ✅`);
}
load();
```

Here is my guildCreate event:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const config1 = require("../config.json");

module.exports =  (client, message,guild) => {

    console.log(`Hi, ${client.user.username} is now serving in ${client.guilds.size} servers and serving ${client.guilds.reduce((c, p) => c + p.memberCount, 0)} users!.`);
        

}
```

Here is my channelCreate event:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = async ( client , channel ) => {
    // event firing when it joins a guild

    
    var log = channel.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name.includes('member-log')) 
    var sEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor("RANDOM")
                .setTitle(`:information_source: A channel Was Created!`)
                .setDescription(`**Name**\n${channel}`)
                .addField(`**Type**`,`${channel.type}`) 
                .setFooter(`ChannelID:${channel.id} | CreatedAT:${channel.createdAt}`);
                log.send(sEmbed);

}
```

What can I do to stop this channelCreate event from firing when joining a guild?

Answer (score 1):

got it `Date.now()/1000+2` wont work it was a bit before than this event even triggered XD .I did this and its working its better as sometimes if the server has too many channel then its better to increase time up to 30 sec its safer

```
client.on("channelCreate", (channel) => {
let x = channel.guild.me.joinedTimestamp / 1000
    if(x <= (x+10)) return; // if the bot just joined the server the channelcreate event will get activated after 10 sec
    console.log("Valid event!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in the Discord.js repository yesterday about it. The only way I find it's to check if the bot joined the server less than 2 seconds ago. For example:

```js
client.on("channelCreate", (channel) => {
    if((channel.guild.me.joinedTimestamp / 1000) < (Date.now()/1000+2)) return;
    console.log("Valid event!");
});
```

Note you can also check if the channel was created less than x seconds. For example if the event receive a channel which was created 2 years ago... it's not a valid event.